# Refreshing scripts in Package Manager Console

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015

I am working on a PowerShell script intended to be run in Package Manager Console. I am able to add a script at the location returned by `$profile` in Package Manager Console, but I am not able to get the script to pick up changes without opening a fresh instance of Visual Studio.

According to this [article](http://blog.marcduiker.nl/2016/12/28/hands-on-with-sitecore-helix-using-powershell-add-module.html), you should be able to reload the script by typing `& $profile`:

> When you make changes to this user profile while Visual Studio is open Visual Studio will not detect any changes. You can type & $profile in the Package Manager Console to reload the profile.

I can use `& $profile` to verify my script does not have syntax errors, but it does not load the changes into the console session, which requires me to open a fresh Visual Studio session every time I make a script change.

For example, if I set my profile script to:

```
function foo{
  Write-Output "bar"
}
```

and then open Visual Studio and Package Manager Console, I can type "foo" at the prompt and get back "bar". If I change "function" to "functionX" and run `& $profile`, I will get a ParserError in the console. But if I change the script body to `Write-Output "baz"` and then run `& $profile` at the console prompt, and I then type foo, I will still get back "bar".  The code change is only picked up in a fresh instance of Visual Studio.

Is there a setting in Visual Studio that changes this behavior or a way to force the new script to be loaded?

Comment: I believe all you need to do is "dot source" `$profile` so it runs in that scope again: `. $profile`

Comment: This did the trick! Please add as an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a script is executed without dot sourcing the variables, functions, etc. defined in that script are not added to the parent scope. By adding a period in front of the command will dot source the script and therefore add things in that parent scope.

In your specific case the command will be:

```
. $profile
```